# two text views with filename and timecreated from sdcard to listview

Tags: listview, datetime, android-listview, arraylist, adapter

My app is where I record the sound and show the recorded files in list.I wanted to create a listview with two textviews. I specify a folder from sd card and which contains audio files I recorded using the app and show the files in a list view. First textview in list is filename and second text is the time or date created. I dont know how to add time to the list.

my code is as follows

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    recordstart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    recordstop  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    recording = false;

    recordstart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {




        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(recordsound.this);

            alert.setTitle("Add Name");


            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
        final EditText input = new EditText(recordsound.this);
            alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
               value = input.getText().toString();
              // Do something with value!

               System.out.println("value is"+ value);

              if(value==""&&value==null){

                  recordstart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                  recordstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter the name  " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                  recordint=1;

              }else{

                  recordstart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                  listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                  recordstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                  recordint=2;

              }


                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();


              timearray.add(today.format("%k:%M:%S"));

              startRecording(v);

              }
            });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
              }
            });

            alert.show();

            startRecording(v);


        }
    });

    recordstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(final View v) {


            stopRecording(v);


        }
    });

   String cardRootnew = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/newrecorder/"; 
    dataPathnew = cardRootnew;

    File folder1 = new File(dataPathnew);
    boolean success = false;
    if (!folder1.exists()) {
        success = folder1.mkdir();
    }

    if (!success) {
    } else { 
    }

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
    myList = new ArrayList<String>();



    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    String cardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/newrecorder/" ; 

    dataPath = cardRoot;

    File directory =new File(dataPath);
    File file = new File( dataPath );
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
            myList.add( list[i].getName() );


    }



     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set all the file in the list.


 // ListView Item Click Listener
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {

       // ListView Clicked item index
       int itemPosition     = position;

       // ListView Clicked item value
        itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String filepath=dataPath + itemValue;

        Intent intent = new Intent(recordsound.this, FilesActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("filepath", filepath);


        intent.putExtra("itemvalue", itemValue);
        startActivity(intent);

        // Show Alert 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          "Playing  " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();

      }

});

}

void playshit()
{

    File sound = new File(dataPath + itemValue);

    Uri soundUri = Uri.fromFile(sound);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundUri);
    mediaPlayer.start();

}


private SeekBar getSeekBar(int id) {
    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(id);
    seekBar.setMax(MIDDLE * 2);
    seekBar.setProgress(MIDDLE);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    return seekBar;
}

public void startRecording(View view) {


    if(recordint==1){

    if (!recording) {
        extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false);


        Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
        today.setToNow();



        extAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(dataPathnew +String.valueOf(today.format("%k:%M:%S")));
        extAudioRecorder.prepare(); 
        extAudioRecorder.start();
        recording = true;


    }

    }else if(recordint==2){


        if (!recording) {
            extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false);

            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();
            extAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(dataPathnew +value+String.valueOf(today.format("%k:%M:%S")));
            extAudioRecorder.prepare(); 
            extAudioRecorder.start();
            recording = true;




            if(timearray!=null){
            System.out.println("today.format is"+ timearray.size());

            }
        }

    }

}

public void stopRecording(View view) {
    if (recording) {
        extAudioRecorder.stop();
        extAudioRecorder.release();
        recording = false;
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void playRecording(View view) {
    File sound = new File(dataPathnew + "output.wav");
    Uri soundUri = Uri.fromFile(sound);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundUri);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    if (seekBar.equals(rateBar)) {
        rate = progress - MIDDLE;
    } else if (seekBar.equals(tempoBar)) {
        tempo = progress - MIDDLE;
    } else if (seekBar.equals(pitchBar)) {
        pitch = progress - MIDDLE;
    }
}

public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {        
}

public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {        
}
```

Please suggest me some ideas as to how to add time to other text view in listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandeep, you are storing the file names in the myList Array right, like that u need to store the time or date of the file into another Array and pass both array's into the adapter and get the file and date from the baseAdapter class based on the positions, its so simple..

adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, myList,myDates);

In the adapter class change the constructor based on the arguments, thats it.

Comment: Yeah i got this idea, but how do i get the time or date created of the file. Is there some method to get the date created of the file.

Comment: I just found this from stack overflow, try this to get the last modified date of the file File f= new File(filePath);
Date fileDate= new Date(f.lastModified());

Comment: thank you so much , But when i use this, i am getting null pointer exception. I cant add this date to an array and pass it to adapter. I can understand why its showing null pointer exception.

Comment: Dude can you post the code how you retrieved the date of the file.

Comment: ok I got this working. thank you so much. Just had to change the date to string and then add it to adapter.